# Julia v0.6 macro inside function

Tags: julia

Can someone resolve this macro error I'm having, it only started happening in version 0.6:

```
mutable struct Foo
    x::Int
end

macro test(myfoo)
    quoteblock = 
    quote
    myfoo.x += 1
    end

    return quoteblock
end

function func(myfoo)
    @test myfoo
    println(myfoo.x)
end

foo = Foo(3)
func(foo)
```

In theory this should just replace the line `@test myfoo` in the function `func` with `myfoo.x += 1` at compile time, which should work, but instead I get the error:

```
UndefVarError: myfoo not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding change-notes are listed [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/NEWS.md#breaking-changes-1):

> When a macro is called in the module in which that macro is defined,
>   global variables in the macro are now correctly resolved in the macro
>   definition environment. *Breakage from this change commonly manifests
>   as undefined variable errors that do not occur under 0.5. Fixing such
>   breakage typically requires sprinkling additional escs in the
>   offending macro* (#15850).

so the answer is to escape `myfoo`:

```
macro test(myfoo)
   quote   
     $(esc(myfoo)).x += 1
   end
end
```

Comment: This resolves my example, but apparently my example didn't capture some subtly in my actual code.  When I include the $(esc()) I now get the undefined error immediately upon trying to load my source code.

Comment: nm, I figured out a way to adapt your solution, thanks.